# How to make a div scroll without the page itself scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I came across this [site](http://jordansowers.com) and thought the effect was really amazing. I wish to replicate this effect in some capacity. I am aware it will involve both css and javascript. Getting the divs rendered and centered on screen is very easy. What I am having issues with is getting each individual to scroll off screen instead of the screen itself scrolling. What effect or strategy can be used to achieve this??

EDIT: I do not wish for a javascript or external library approach. Thank you

Comment: I feel like this site is in the fashion industry of web design

Comment: They are using on("scroll") to animate each object/tile. Could also be made with binding on("touchmove") for mobile support. The object isn't in fact scrolling, it's being animated for when the user is scrolling. I can make a fiddle for you if you like.

Comment: @Crashtor Yes please that would help a lot

Comment: I noticed that the site is styling the scrollbar and hiding it.
ie:  .ios .screen ::-webkit-scrollbar, ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 0!important;
    width: 0!important;
    display: none;
}
So the images are scrolling off the of the screen using native scrolling (You can disable these styles in the dev tools have the hidden scrollbar revealed). However each image is fixed in place via css classes that are applied at the right time. The .collage-image class has posittion: fixed; by default. .is-released class is added to each collage-image in turn when it is their turn to scroll.

Comment: I would expect that you can't pull this off without javascript. You can actually see his javascript code that does the effect by doing the following: In the chrome dev tools, go to sources panel, the navigate to the app.min.js file. Chrome has a beautify feature where you click the {} icon at the bottom and it'll make the 1 liner more readable. The code is actually not minified so now you can see everything, including full function/var names. browse to releaseImage function and set a breakpoint there (line 1953). Scroll on the webpage to trigger the effect and then step thru the code.

Comment: When I wrote my edit I meant jquery. That was my mistake. I did not want jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No matter what, **you will need a little bit of JavaScript** to accomplish the effect shown in the link you provided.

Here is an example that more-or-less shows how the effect works:

```js
var active = 0;
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.wrap > div')

function onScroll(){

  var winHeight = window.innerHeight
  var scrollAmt = document.body.scrollTop;
  var newActive = Math.floor( scrollAmt / winHeight )
  
  if( active != newActive ){
    active = newActive;
    
    divs.forEach(function(el, indx){
      if( indx <= active )
        el.classList.add('released')
      else
        el.classList.remove('released')
    })
    
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
```

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  min-height: 400vh;
}

.wrap > div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrap > div > div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}

.wrap > div.first { z-index: 3; }
.wrap > div.second { z-index: 2; }
.wrap > div.third { z-index: 1; }

.wrap > div.first > div {
  background: blue;
  height: 60%;
}

.wrap > div.second > div {
  background: yellow;
  width: 55%;
  height: 55%;
}

.wrap > div.third > div{
  background: green;
  width: 60%;
}

.wrap > div.released {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="first released"><div></div></div>
  <div class="second"><div></div></div>
  <div class="third"><div></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use  **overflow: auto;** or  **overflow: scroll;** in the css for the div.

```css
.container {
  
   height: 100px; 
   overflow: auto; /*you can also use overflow: scroll; option */
}
```

```html
<div class ='container'>
1<br>
2<br>
3<br>
4<br>
5<br>
6<br>
7<br>
8<br>
9<br>
10<br>

</div>
```

Comment: The site he is referring to is doing a fancier 'trick' than just overflow: auto;